# How to make rounded slides in swiper.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import SwiperCore, {
  Navigation,
  Pagination,
  EffectFade,
  EffectCoverflow,
  EffectCube,
} from "swiper";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
import "./App.css";

SwiperCore.use([
  EffectCoverflow,
  EffectCube,
  EffectFade,
  Navigation,
  Pagination,
]);

const slides = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  slides.push(
    <SwiperSlide key={`slide-${i}`}>
      <img
        src={`https://picsum.photos/id/${i + 1}/500/300`}
        style={{ listStyle: "none" }}
        alt={`Slide ${i}`}
      />
    </SwiperSlide>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Swiper
        initialSlide="2"
        effect="coverflow"
        navigation
        grabCursor={true}
        centeredSlides={true}
        slidesPerView="3"
        coverflowEffect={{
          rotate: 50,
          stretch: 0,
          depth: 300,
          modifier: 3,
        }}
      >
        {slides}
      </Swiper>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CSS code

```
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

I want to make all slides like a rounded circle. I am not able to do that in swiperjs. Can anyone help me in doing this. Here is the link of what I have done till now.

I tried doing it using border-radius and applied it to many classes and also used !important but was not able to achieve that.

https://nifty-rosalind-68dc39.netlify.app/

Comment: for `img` tag set .style `border-radius: 50%;`

Comment: You need to set `img,swiper-slide-shadow-left,swiper-slide-shadow-right` to `border-radius:50%`

Comment: I did that but could not get perfect circle. Its like oval shape

Comment: I have updated the link

Answer (score 1):

I think you must add a `div` inside `.swiper-slide` and give that equal width and height, then you can use `border-radius: 100%`. in this case you must use [auto slides per view](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/120-slides-per-view-auto.html) in swiper option.

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
 <div class="round-item">
  <img src="..." alt="..." />
 </div>
</div>
```

```
.swiper-slide .round-item {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 100%;

 overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-slide .round-item img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I did that but didnt work. I have updated the link for the same.

Comment: I read your code in inspect element, and turns out `.round-item` is a circle now but images inside it are not. I'll update my answer to show you how must change `img` css

Comment: And I need to change width for large and extra large devices because of fixed width size

Comment: There will be no problem until `.round-item` width smaller than the viewport width, you can reduce `.round-item` width to 300px when the viewport smaller than 568px and for the greater size, swiper will automatically show the items @ronakpatel

Comment: worked great for me thanks! but I only needed a border-radius: 15px; to get some nice rounded corners :)